# Sitecore Mobile SDK issue with more data

Tags: mobile, xamarin, sdk, sitecore, bucket

We are using [Mobile SDK for Xamarin](https://doc.sitecore.net/mobile_sdk_for_xamarin/managing_content_with_the_mobile_sdk/the_item_request_configuration_parameters) for getting SiteCore Data for our apps.  We are using the [Task.WaitAll() method](https://dev.sitecore.net/mobile%20sdk%20for%20xamarin/managing%20content%20with%20the%20mobile%20sdk/executing%20requests).

We are sending SiteCore FAST queries to Mobile SDK to get items that are updated in last 15 minutes, for example:

```
fast:/sitecore/content/Home/Articles//*[@@templateid='{2FA3421A-F179-46B6-B8D9-5C65CB4A6584}'and @__Updated > '20160209T194700Z']
```

and the output results set will be approximately 1-10 items, which is very small.

This worked fine when we had less data in a SiteCore Bucket `/sitecore/content/Home/Articles`. But now, SiteCore Bucket `/sitecore/content/Home/Articles` has 45823 items and it fails with error `A Tas was cancelled` when `Task.WaitAll()` is invoked from the App.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - don't use fast query or a sitecore query with that many items. Your code is probably timing out.

You need to use the Search API and query the Sitecore index (Lucene or SOLR) when dealing with large numbers of items. Sitecore Query and Fast Query will *always* be too slow. In fact fast query can really kill your SQL Server if you are not careful: http://blog.coates.dk/2014/11/19/sitecore-fast-query-syntax-can-kill-your-sql-server-or-website/